# How to retrieve the post_id of a tag page?

Tags: tags

Thought this would be straight forward... given a tag page such as `http://domain.com/blog/tag/tag-1/` how can I retrieve the `post_id` while on that page?

The usual suspects such as `url_to_postid` and `$post->ID` or `$wp_query->post->ID` do not return anything.  The hook that calls the function is running during `init`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tag page would be like other archive pages in that a loop of posts would be displayed, even if only one post has been assigned that tag.

You're check for post ID needs to happen during the `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` loop.

Comment: Ah... don't think I can do that since this is a plugin and not a theme.  Is there any way I can treat a tag page differently from within my plugin?

Comment: You may want to look into using `add_action( 'the_post', 'your_action_function' );` in your plugin. That hooks in and returns an array of post data to the specified function.

Comment: AWESOME!  That looks like it's precisely what I needed.  Thanks!!

Comment: I've run into one unfortunate problem with this solution.  The hook I need to use this with, must execute at one of several possible points, including `init`, `wp_loaded`, and a few others.  Unfortunately all of these cause the passing of the post data to fail, and so I'm not able to pick up the fact that I'm on a tag page.  Any idea how I can use `is_tag` or similar functions within `init`?